# Wireless internet automatically (and randomly) loses connection on laptop

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, laptop, disconnect

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop

My computer automatically and randomly loses internet connection while still connected to the wifi network (it keeps the display on the top bar, but I haven't confirmed).

Disconnecting and Reconnecting to the wifi network restores internet connection.

Please comment all the info that'd be required to troubleshoot my problem so that people can figure out what's wrong.

Regards,
ryzokuken

**INFORMATION:**

Laptop Model: `Acer Aspire E 15 : E5-573G-39G8`

Wireless Card: `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller`

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 2c:60:0c:f6:16:a6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4404000-c4404fff memory:c4400000-c4403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 30
       serial: 48:e2:44:45:f5:6f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:c4200000-c43fffff
```

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Ujjwal"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 90:8D:78:18:C9:51   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:27  Invalid misc:1910   Missed beacon:0

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `lpsci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Wireless card? Laptop Model?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Wireless, or wired, connection problem? For your wireless controller, you called out a PCIe gigabit ethernet controller. If you're really talking about a wired connection problem, there's a problem with the r8169 driver, and there's a fix for that. Please advise. Cheers, Al

Comment: Please post: `iwconfig` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema, the problem is concerning wireless connection

Comment: Is this a wireless driver issue? Please help. Bump.